# How to "reconnect" to a service with an activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm starting to make an Android app that stream music from a radio station. So i have an activity which retrieve the info about the artist, title and the cover of the album. And also everything which about the UI (play, pause, Quit and change the bandwidth). Everything works fine when i first launch the app but when i pressed the home button and i relaunch the application Android recreate the activity (by passing by onResume etc). But my service with the musicPlayer continues to play and then i cannot send instructions from the activity because the activity can't access to the Service.
So my question is when the activity is recreate with onResume etc how can we sends informations to the service.
Here's how i create the service and sends information to it:

```
onCreate(){
...
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Play.class);
    intent.putExtra("play", true);
    intent.putExtra("pause", false);
    intent.putExtra("stop", false);
    intent.putExtra("artist", artist);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("speed", "low");
    intent.putExtra("restart", restart);
    startService(intent);
    restart = false;
...
}
```

I saw that there's exist onBind() function but i'm not sure how it's works neither if it's this that i'm needed.

Thank you in advance
P.S. Hope my english isn't too bad

Comment: Have a look at Bound Services  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Thank you but it says : A bound service typically lives only while it serves another application component and does not run in the background indefinitely.
As i want to have the music play indefinitely until i choose to stop

Comment: You must have missed this paragraph:"When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the service (unless the service was also started by startService())."

Comment: OK so if i use bound service and i call it by startService it would work ?

Comment: I think so. I've only used bind autocreate myself, but the documentation seems to point that way. Best thing would be for you to try it and see, good luck